# How handle "left" and "right" key on Prototype?

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs, keypress

I need manipulate "left" and "right" key on prototype, something like http://mangastream.com/

Comment: Can you please explain more?  There's no real question in here and there's not enough information to guess what you might mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as:

```
$(document).observe('keydown', function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case Event.KEY_LEFT:
            e.stop(); // prevent the default action, like horizontal scroll
            window.location = '/read/prev';
            break;
        case Event.KEY_RIGHT:
            e.stop();
            window.location = '/read/next';
            break;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pMts6/

`Event.KEY_LEFT` and `Event.KEY_RIGHT` are their handy constants for the numerical codes of the corresponding keys.

Read up on Prototype events at http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/.

Comment: have a way to avoid left and rigth key "check" a radiobutton in this code?

Comment: no...my HTML have only a radio-group with four radiobuttons, when you select one and press "left" or "right", the next radio button is checked...have way to avoid this?